# Asp.net RenderControl method not rendering autopostback for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, rendercontrol

i am bit confused as to why asp.net does not render a dropdownlist with the autopostback property set to true when using the RenderControl method.

eg

```
 Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter
    Dim tw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    Dim table As New Table

    table.Rows.Add(New TableRow)
    Dim tr As TableRow = table.Rows(0)

    tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell)
    Dim tc As TableCell = tr.Cells(0)

    Dim ddlMyValues As New DropDownList
    ddlMyValues.ID = "ddl1"

    ddlMyValues.Items.Add("Test1")
    ddlMyValues.Items.Add("Test2")
    ddlMyValues.Items.Add("Test3")
    ddlMyValues.AutoPostBack = True

    tc.Controls.Add(ddlMyValues)
    table.RenderControl(tw)

    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ToString)
```

> my output renders the dropdown list without the onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\ddl1\',\'\')', 0)"
>     that is generated by asp.net when using the dropdownlist normally.

Is there a work around to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it might be because it's not inside a `form` element. Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Hi Ian, i am working with a control that another developer created, and he goes through this routine to create a row of controls. I am extend his control by adding a validation to drop downs which i cannot achieve!

Comment: Sounds like an awful mess. If you don't need to dynamically create HTML output why not just put the controls in a usercontrol rather than  using the HTMLWriter?